# Botkit unauthorized when connecting through emulator (Microsoft Bot Framework)

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, chatbot, botkit

I would like to set up botkit to use the Microsoft Bot Framework.

botkit refers to the yeoman generator on their "Get started" page: https://botkit.ai/getstarted.html

This generator asks an App ID and App Password.

I went to my created channel in azure -> Settings to get my App id. Copied the value from "Microsoft App ID" and hovering over the information icon tells me to click "Manage" to get a password.
Clicked "Manage" which leads me to a "Not found" page. (According to old articles this should have worked, i guess this is because of the migration? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-quickstart-registration?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

afterwards i followed a microsoft blog post about retrieving app passwords here: https://blog.botframework.com/2018/07/03/find-your-azure-bots-appid-and-appsecret/

After entering this in the emulator as explained in the steps. it says: "Unauthorized".

As a messaging endpoint i put my ngrok forwarded url. (retrieved using `./ngrok http 3000`)

Is there anything I'm missing? It should be pretty straight forward to get this working normally no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Botkit to work with the BotFramework, you only need a few items to be configured. Compare what you have with the below, note any differences, and make the appropriate changes. I have this simple setup working.

First, this is how you can locate your BotFramework appId & appPassword, if you don't know it.

Navigate to your Azure bot's resource group. On the left menu pane, select Deployments.
[image]

Then select the bot deployment and select Inputs in the menu pane. This will then list your appId and appPassword.

[image]

Place this code in your index.js file. Be sure to do the necessary npm installs.

```js
const { MemoryStorage } = require('botbuilder');
const { Botkit, BotkitBotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botkit');
const path = require('path');

// Note: Ensure you have a .env file.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
require('dotenv').config({ path: ENV_FILE });

const storage = new MemoryStorage();

const controller = new Botkit({
  adapter: BotkitBotFrameworkAdapter,
  adapterConfig: {
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
  },
  storage: storage,
  webhook_uri: '/api/messages',
});

controller.hears('hello', 'message', async function(bot, message) {
  await bot.reply(message, 'Hello yourself');
});
```

Include your appId and appPassword in a .env file with the following set up.

```
MicrosoftAppId=<appId>
MicrosoftAppPassword=<appPassword>
```

Run the bot from the project's root directory with `node index.js`.

Lastly, in Emulator, set the messaging endpoint to `http://localhost:3000/api/messages` and include the same 'Microsoft App Id' and 'Microsoft App password' credentials.

[image]

Once Emulator is setup, test by typing a message. The bot is expecting 'hello' and will only respond to that user input.

You should be good to go, at this point.

Hope of help!